# How can I check if returned value is true in one line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm running the following command in bash:

```bsh
yarn config get workspaces-experimental
```

Which returns the following:

```bsh
true\n
\n
```

That is, "true" or "false" followed by two end lines. I want to take this process, verify its standard output and pipe it into another process that returns an exit code when the result is not "true".

How can I do this? Use the vertical bar (|)?

Comment: `true` as in literal string or you are taking about exit codes/

Comment: I think a literal string. In the terminal, what gets printed is the word "true" followed by two end lines.

Comment: Did you check the actual return code? You might be making things more complicated than needed.

Comment: @Panki yarn returns "false" and returns no error code when "workspaces-experimental" is not activated. This is what I want to check in one line.

Comment: So it returns 0 when printing 'false'?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg "returns" can be ambiguous - are you trying to test the *standard output* of the command (i.e. what gets printed in a terminal) or its *exit status* (what would be printed by `echo $?` after the command has run)? Usually it's simpler and more robust to test the latter

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, the "standard output" is what I'm interested in, and I want to pipe this process with another one that returns with an exit code when the output is not "true"

Comment: @Panki no, but I want to pipe another process that does that

Comment: When you run that command and it returns `true`, please run `echo $?` and let us know the result. Similarly, if you can get it to return the word `false` (or whatever alternative it gives you to `true`), please also then immediately run `echo $?` and let us know the result.

Comment: @roaima `echo $?` returns "0" in both cases. [Here's a screen capture for you](https://imgur.com/a/dUNpzjt).

Comment: just use `yarn ... | grep -q true`. The accepted answer won't work in a standard shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash`, this will generate an exit status code of 0 (success) only when the text literal `true` is matched. In other cases it will return non-zero (failure)

```
[[ $(yarn config get workspaces-experimental) == true ]]
```

You can use this directly in a conditional statement, for example

```
if [[ $(yarn config get workspaces-experimental) == true ]]
then
    echo "Relax, everything is fine"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pipe to `xargs` and use `test`:

```bsh
yarn config get workspaces-experimental | xargs test true =
```